# Border with transformed edge

Tags: html, css

maybe my title is not good description about the thing i want to ask, i need specific border and i dont have any idea how to do it.

http://prntscr.com/eaqmcs

```
        <div class="row first-column">
            <h2>100%</h2>
            <h1 class="col-md-12">Monetize your Mobile <span>Traffic</span></h1>
            <p class="col-md-5 offset-md-4 pull-right">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officia ducimus veniam earum! Architecto omnis ex nobis nemo enim culpa, 
                natus deleniti assumenda accusantium inventore laboriosam soluta perferendis, corporis facilis sunt?
            </p>
        </div>
```

This is my css

```
.first-column{
   margin-left: 18%;
   margin-right: 18%;
   margin-top: -5%;
}
.first-column h1{
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #acacac;
}
.first-column h2{
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 13%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 57px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve this effect using skew transformation.
as the shape you have given is like a skewed div with only bottom and right radius

```css
.test{
width: 150px;
height: 10px;
margin-left: 100px;
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
border-right: 4px solid red;
transform: skewX(-60deg);
border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=test></div>
```

Comment: thank you very much i really appreciate it

Comment: cool.. no problem.. you can also look at svg its better for these kind of things

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements, like `h1 span:after`, to achieve the effect:

http://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/jyjrmz